# On delete action and update trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am not an experienced person in db related parts.
Here is my doubt. i am using MySQL
I have two tables assume

- **project**  (columns :- pid, folder_id, p_name)
- **folder** (columns :- folder_id, name)

And i created two triggers for table project

- trgr_project_before_insert
- trgr_project_before_update

And there is a foreign key relation with folder and project.
ie folder_id in `folder` table is referring in 'project' table.
And i set "**ON DELETE**" action with "**Set null**" in project table. 
ie when the "**folder_id**" deleted in `folder` table then MySQL will set NULL for those rows have deleted "**folder_id**"

And in my "trgr_project_before_update" trigger i have some code that checking

```
NEW.folder_id IS NULL THEN 
 --some code are here 
END IF;
```

when i delete one "**folder_id**" from **folder** table then all the rows have that "**folder_id**" are set with NULL i think its updating the table. 
but the trigger "trgr_project_before_update" doesn't work(codes inside my checking) why is that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like a MySQL bug - [bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11472](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11472)

When rows of a table are updated/deleted indirectly as a result of a foreign key definition on the table, triggers on that table are not executed as required

They says like "We should fix in 5.1" please check MySQL version.